What's the significance of lightmaps, and what are good techniques to use while making them?
I'm trying to develop a pack of assets to sell on the Unreal Engine marketplace. On submission, I was told my lightmaps were overlapping and needed to be redone.
Normally this isn't an issue. But since I'm putting together a stylized low-poly pack, the way I've been UV projecting (looking from one side, selecting all, and then projecting from view) has made the lightmaps extremely bad.
I'm right now manually going back and reconstructing the lightmaps by hand, but I'm wondering:
A. If There is a faster way to do this, or if I've gotta just do it by hand
B. What the significance of lightmaps is and good practices for making them properly
C. If selecting all, marking every edge as a seam (on a stylized, low-poly mesh, mind you) and then unwrapping is a bad idea (I'm very new to lightmaps. Like, two hours new.)

What do you mean "by hand"? In order to tell you about a faster method, people will need to know what the thing that it needs to be faster than is. What do you mean, by asking about significance? What are you using them for? Is that significant to you? Well that's the significance then. If you don't know what they are for, you should not be making them, should you? Could you edit the question and clarify? I think it is not possible to answer otherwise.

Lightmap UVs are usually a 2nd set of UVs where every vertex in the UV is aligned exactly to the pixels , with no overlaps between shells. I would recommend reading this article from polycount about the topic. It's pretty old-school but it should get you started.

Light maps are a thing of game engines, not Blender. Although you technically can bake lightmaps in Blender, it is more of an attempt to mimick what is done in Game Engines, and in your case you are clearly working on Unreal Engine that really doesn't need you to use any other software to make lightmaps, so it's out of topic here.
That being said, you indeed can't use overlapping UVs for them, as they need to be able to bake lighting for the entire object and overlapping UVs lead to parts of the mesh unable to be baked properly.
Using "Project From view" essentially unwraps the UVs as you see the mesh in the viewport, so it will be almost exclusively overlapped.
Either make UVs manually using seams, or use an automated UV unwrapping such as Smart UV Project.
Also, I believe some game engines have options to automatically generate UVs for light maps, but gain: that's out of topic here, so I live it up to you to look that up.
More about it:

Understanding Lightmapping in Unreal Engine | Unreal Engine 5.4 Documentation | Epic Developer Community
Bake Lightmaps (Light Maps) – Blender Knowledgebase
Naxela/The_Lightmapper: Fast and easy baked GI Lightmaps for Blender and Cycles

